# How do I fix my dropdown menu in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am making a navbar for my project which has several dropdown menus, here is my navbar code:

```
<nav>
    <a class="logo" href="{% url 'home' %}">LOGO</a>

    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn" id="dropdown-btn">Teacher <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> </a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="{% url 'teacher:add-teacher' %}">Add Teacher</a>
                <a href="{% url 'teacher:list-teacher' %}">List Teacher</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn" id="dropdown-btn">Blog <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> </a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="{% url 'blog:blog-form' %}">Add Blog</a>
                <a href="#">Blog List</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I want that onclick of dropdown-btn, it shows dropdown-content. I tried below code, but it gives the following error in console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

and this is my javascript Code. `.dropdown-content` has a display of none and `active-dropdown` has `display:block` in it

```
let i, dropdownBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
for (i = 0; i < dropdownBtns.length; i++) {
    dropdownBtns[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        panel.classList.toggle('active-dropdown');
    });
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1) Your loop was using an `i` that was outside of its scope

2) You were using the new `() => {}` fat arrow function syntax which doesn't bind `this` to the function - so you were referring to the `window` when you wrote `this.nextElementSibling`.

Try this:

```
var dropdownBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");

for (var i = 0; i < dropdownBtns.length; i++) {
    dropdownBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        panel.classList.toggle('active-dropdown');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your arrow function was using a different `this` - also, look at your scoping for `i`:

```
var dropdownBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");

for (let i = 0; i < dropdownBtns.length; i++) {
    dropdownBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        panel.classList.toggle('active-dropdown');
    });
}
```